# Using SizeTransition to animate in a pageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter

I want to use the `SizeTransition` animation to animate my page route, but there is no effect when I run it.
Here is my code

```
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          PageRouteBuilder(
                            transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            transitionsBuilder:
                                (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                              return SizeTransition(
                                sizeFactor: animation,
                                axis: Axis.vertical,
                                axisAlignment: 0,
                                child: child,
                              );
                            },
                            pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                              return CreateUpdateNoteView();
                            },
                            settings: RouteSettings(arguments: note),
                          ),
                        );
```

This is the effect I am going for
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we do not have the animation itself so it is kind of hard to say what is missing exactly but 2 things:

1. even though you put a transition it doesn't mean that the animation itself has a duration so:

- building a controller

  ```
    class YourClass extends State<XXX> with 
                                              SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
     late AnimationController controller;


      @override
      void initState() {
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(second: 2),
        ); // automatically animation will be started
      }
  ```
- then add it in your sizeTransition:

  ```
  Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          PageRouteBuilder(
                            transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            transitionsBuilder:
                                (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                              return SizeTransition(
                                sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
                                            curve: Curves.linear,
                                            parent: controller
                                            ),
                                axis: Axis.vertical,
                                axisAlignment: 0,
                                child: child,
                              );
                            },
                            pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                              return CreateUpdateNoteView();
                            },
                            settings: RouteSettings(arguments: note),
                          ),
                        );
  ```

2. A package exist for this exact purpose and is developped by flutter.dev, it is animations (can be found here: https://pub.dev/packages/animations#container-transform) and there is a codelab (can be found here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-flutter#4), this will definitely help you.

Hope it could help